# Debugging a child process in python using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: python, visual-studio-2019

I have a script called `main.py` which makes use of `subprocess` to call a script called `called.py`:

**main.py**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import sys

user_input = ['John', '555']

communicate_argument = '\n'.join(user_input)
p = Popen([sys.executable, 'called.py'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, encoding='utf-8')

stdout, stderr = p.communicate(communicate_argument)

print(stdout)
```

**called.py**

```
name = input('What is your name\n')
age = input('What is your age\n')

print('You are {}, and you are {} years old'.format(name, age))
```

I would like to call `main`, but debug `called` in VS2019. I made a solution and am successfully able to run and debug `main.py`.

However, if I place a breakpoint in `called.py`, the debugger won't stop there, and will instead execute the program to completion.

How can I successfully debug `called.py` if it is being run from `main.py`??

Comment: Any special reason you are not importing it as a module?

Comment: Yes. In reality, `called` is a large, poorly designed 3rd party program which I need to test before refactoring. I don't want to change the fact that it takes in user input until I am able to test all its functionality...